# Unmount busy filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, umount

I'm trying to unmount a backup filesystem that I don't need anymore. When I run the "umount" command, system says:

```
umount: /backup: target is busy
```

And following commands does not work and same reason (busy) returns to me:

```
fuser -cuk /backup
fuser -k -9 /backup
umount -f /backup
mount -o remount /backup; umount /backup
```

and

```
lsof |grep /backup | grep -v "backup.log"
```

command returns nothing already. (grep -v is because ignore backup.log files. If I'm wrong I can change.)

Why I cannot umount this filesystem and how can I do?

---

Edit:

Commands those are I tried and outputs of them:

```
myserver:~ # fuser -cuk /backup
myserver:~ # fuser -k -9 /backup
myserver:~ # umount -f /backup
umount: /backup: target is busy
    (In some cases useful info about processes that
     use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
myserver:~ # mount -o remount /backup; umount /backup
umount: /backup: target is busy
    (In some cases useful info about processes that
     use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
myserver:~ #
```

OS Version:

```
myserver:~ # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES_SAP"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for SAP Applications 12 SP2"
ID="sles_sap"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles_sap:12:sp2"
```

And when I check the I/O with "iostat" command I see the physical disk (/dev/sdx) that mounted to this filesystem, there are reading but no writing.

Mounted list:

```
myserver:~ # mount | grep backup
/dev/mapper/vgbackup-lvbackup on /backup type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Comment: yes. none of them works. How can I check respawned processes? If there is one of them, how can't I see this processes or open files? It's so weird.

Comment: One thing that doesn't show in lsof is mount points. So, if you have mounted something to a directory in that filesystem, or mounted a file from that FS somewhere else (`mount -o loop ...`) they won't show in lsof but prevent umounting.

Comment: I cannot see anything that mounted to /backup or under of /backup at neither fstab nor df -h command.

Comment: my question format has been broken :) it doesn't show code blocks. I'm so lucky today. (ok that was my fault. i fixed it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this question on Linux & Unix SE: [umount: device is busy. Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15024/108618)

Few answers:

1. > It seems the cause for my issue was the `nfs-kernel-server` was exporting the directory. The `nfs-kernel-server` probably goes behind the normal open files and thus is not listed by `lsof` and `fuser`.
   >
   > When I stopped the `nfs-kernel-server` I could `umount` the directory.
2. > the cause for my manifestation of this problem just now was a stale loopback mount. I'd already checked the output of `fuser -vm <mountpoint>/lsof +D <mountpoint>`, `mount` and `cat /proc/mounts`, checked whether some old nfs-kernel-server was running, turned off quotas, attempted (but failed) a `umount -f <mountpoint>` and all but resigned myself to abandoning 924 days' uptime before finally checking the output of `losetup` and finding two stale configured-but-not-mounted loopbacks
3. > For me, the offending process was a daemon running in a chroot. Because it was in a chroot, `lsof` and `fuser` wouldn't find it.
   >
   > If you suspect you have something left running in a chroot, `sudo ls -l /proc/*/root | grep chroot` will find the culprit (replace "chroot" with the path to the chroot).
4. > Anonymous inodes
   >
   > […]
   >
   > These are the most elusive type of pokemon, and appear in `lsof`'s `TYPE` column as `a_inode` (which is undocumented in the `lsof` man page).
   >
   > They won't appear in `lsof +f -- /dev/<device>`, so you'll need to:
   >
   > ```
   > lsof | grep a_inode
   > ```